# I am having a difficult time understanding what I am doing wrong with quadratics. $5x^2-15x-4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I think I am missing a key part of solving quadratic equations. When I solve by grouping, I run into an issue of my values being incorrect, even though I am doing the same thing to both sides of the equation. Could someone explain to me why this doesn't work and what foundation I need to revisit? Here is my work:
$$
\begin{align}
5x^2-15x-4&=0\\
5x^2 -15x &= 4\\
5x^2–15x-20&=-16\\
5x^2–20x+5x-20&=-16\\
5x(x-4)+5(x-4)&=-16\\
(5x+5)(x-4)&=-16\\
\implies x=-4.20, -12
\end{align}
$$

Comment: As David G. Stork wrote, somehow you got the idea that $ab=c$ implies $a=c$ or $b=c$. This is wrong. This is only true if $c=0$. ie: if $ab=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$. But not for any other c.

Comment: I highly recommend learning mathjax notation. It will make your formulas look much better: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/29979

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you to everyone. I have been reading your answers and have also worked through the proof of the quadratic formula. I see now the difference between factoring and completing the square. It has been probably ~7 years since I have touched algebra and I am just trying to rebuild those foundations. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us follow your approach: till $(5x+5)(x-4) = -16$, all your statements are correct.  Now you still need to find which values of $x$ satisfy this, and those are the roots.

However none of the values you mention satisfy - for e.g. taking $x = -12$, this statement reads $(-60+5)(-12-4) = -55\cdot -16 = 880 \neq -16$.

If the RHS of $-16$ factors as $a\times b$ for some $a, b$, and you can find a solution for $x$ which **simultaneously** satisfies $5x+5=a, x-4=b$, indeed you have a solution.  However such factors aren't obvious and in general finding them may be tougher than solving the original quadratic through other methods.  Further, you may get only one value of $x$ through this approach, for the other root, you will have to keep checking other possible factorisations.

The only case where you can **independently** set any one the factors in LHS to equal the RHS to find roots, is when the RHS is $0$, for obvious reasons.  This is what you seem to have done, but except when RHS is $0$, this may not solve the original problem. Another e.g. where you may find this working is $(2x-3)(3-x)=1$, due to the coincidence of the factorisation $1^2=1$, even so that gives you only one of the roots.

Hence this approach isn't useful in most cases, and others have suggested valid approaches such as completing the square, or using the quadratic formula, both of which works always.

Comment: Thank you so much! This explanation was exactly what I needed, and I really appreciated your example of the coincidence. The concept is becoming more clear, especially after I worked out the quadratic formula proof!

Comment: Glad that helped!

Answer (score 5):

Your fundamental error is thinking that if $a b = c$ then the two "solutions" are $a = c$ and $b = c$.

Comment: Thank you for your response and your time. Why is it that if I prepared the equation in a way that was a perfect square, that the square root of (ax+b)^2 =c is equal to those values? Why is this assumption right but ab=c is incorrect? Both approaches treat both sides of the equation as f(x)=0 before solving.

Comment: @Zippeh, if you have $(ax+b)^2=c$ then you can either take the square immediately or you can do this $(ax+b)^2-c = 0$. Then factor $(ax+b-\sqrt{c})(ax+b+\sqrt{c})=0$ Then you know that $ax+b-\sqrt{c}=0$ or $ax+b+\sqrt{c}=0$. You are able to do this because you have the product of two things is zero. But this isn't what you had in your problem. Are you trying to complete the square?

Comment: I am just trying to understand why grouping vs completing the square works in particular circumstances. This is starting to make more sense to me. What I don't understand is that, why is it that when I take the root of a square, I get the 0? For this problem, here is what produces the correct results, yet the right side of the equation is not 0.
x^2 -15x-4=0

5(x^2–3x)=4

5(x^2–(2)(x)(1.5)+(1.5)^2-(1.5)^2)=4

5(x-1.5)^2–11.25=4

5(x-1.5)^2=15.25

(x-1.5)^2=3.05

(x-1.5)=+√3.05 or -√3.05

x=√(3.05 )+1.5

x=3.25 

or

x=-√(3.05)+1.5

x=-0.25

Comment: If you have $MK = -16$ there are an infinite number of pairs that $M,K$ can be and you don't really have anyway of knowing which of those infinite number of pairs work and which ones don't.  If you have $(ax+b)^2 = c$ then you have a condition that $MK=c$ *and* $M=K$ that's enough to tell us which pairs are valid. And if you have $MK=0$ then you have $M=0$ or $K=0$.  But if *all* you have is $MK=-16$ then you just don't have enough.

Comment: Boom, thank you fleablood. This was the cherry on top for me! :)

Comment: If $MK = 25$ then you can have $M$ be *ANYTHING* (except  $0$) and so long as $K = \frac {25}M$ this will work.  So you can have $M=1$ and $K=25$ or $M = \pi$ and $K=\frac {25}\pi$ or you can have $M=2572$ and $K=\frac{25}{2572}$. and you have no idea *which* pair works.  But if you have $M^2 = 25$ yoou must have $M=M$ so that leaves only $M =5$ or $M =-5$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to complete the square in your problem?

$5x^2-15x-4 = 0$

Then you'd need to do this:

$5x^2-15x = 4$

Then divide by 5:

$x^2-3x=\frac{4}{5}$

Now complete the square:

$x^2-3x + (\frac{-3}{2})^2 = \frac{4}{5} + (\frac{-3}{2})^2$

$(x-\frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{4}{5}+\frac{9}{4}$

$(x-\frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{61}{20}$

$(x-\frac{3}{2})^2 = (\sqrt{\frac{61}{20}})^2$

$(x-\frac{3}{2})^2 - (\sqrt{\frac{61}{20}})^2 = 0$

Now you can factor this using $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$

$(x-\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{61}{20}})(x-\frac{3}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{61}{20}}) = 0$

Now you can use that ab=0 means a=0 or b=0.

So

$x-\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{61}{20}}=0$

or

$x-\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{61}{20}}=0$

So solving these two gives

$x = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{61}{5}} \approx3.2464$

or

$x = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{61}{5}} \approx0.2464$

Does this help at all?

I could also have done it like this:

$5x^2-15x = 4$

$5(x^2-3x) = 4$

$5(x^2-3x+(\frac{-3}{2})^2) - 5(\frac{-3}{2})^2 = 4$

$5(x-\frac{3}{2})^2 - \frac{45}{4} = 4$

$5(x-\frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{61}{4}$

$(x-\frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{61}{20}$

Then take the square root of both sides. That gives

$x-\frac{3}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{61}{20}}$ or

$x-\frac{3}{2} = -\sqrt{\frac{61}{20}}$

which gives the same two solutions.

Comment: Thank you Ameet for all your help, I really appreciate your time to explain this to me!